# XSLT Muenchian grouping - strange behavior

Tags: .net, xslt

I am using Muenchian grouping in XSLT in .NET to group indicator elements by date.

Snippet of my XML and XSLT:

```
<financials>
  <indicator>
    <date>2010</date>
    <labeltype>2</labeltype>
  </indicator>
  <indicator>
    <date>2009</date>
    <labeltype>2</labeltype>
  </indicator>
  <indicator>
    <date>2008</date>
    <labeltype>2</labeltype>
  </indicator>
  ...
</financials>

<xsl:key name="financialsByDate" match="indicator" use="date" />
<xsl:template match="financials">
    <xsl:for-each select="indicator[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('financialsByDate', date)[1])]">
      <financial>
         ...
      </financial>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

This code works perfectly fine in small XML document I extracted for testing but does not work at all in original XML/XSLT with more elements.

What is strange that when I change text 'date' to 'foobar' it works then.

Is this possible that some other 'date' elements somewhere else in the docuemnt are affecting my code?

Comment: Or do you have other `indicator` elements elsewhere? Try making the key's `match` more specific, e.g. `match="financials/indicator"`

Comment: Great. I've made my comment into a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other `indicator` elements are more likely to be a problem than other `date` elements. The essential thing with Muenchian grouping is that the `key` should match only the elements you are trying to group, so try a more specific key such as

```
<xsl:key name="financialsByDate"
   match="financials/indicator" use="date" />
```